Logic behind hypothesis testing and one-tailed tests
Suppose I have the following:

Let's consider a hypothetical experiment to determine whether James Bond can tell the difference between a shaken and a stirred martini. Suppose we gave James Bond a series of 16 taste tests. In each test, we flipped a fair coin to determine whether to stir or shake the martini. Then we presented the martini to James Bond and asked him to decide whether it was shaken or stirred. Let's say Mr. Bond was correct on 13 of the 16 taste tests.
Given a hypothesis that he was simply guessing, we may compute the probability of guessing 13 or more times. This is equal to 0.0106.

I'm confused on the "13 or more times" part (which I think is called a tail test).
It seems like we are taking some interval of the distribution (in this case 13 or more) and calculating the probability of the sample falling into that interval.
Fine. But why that interval in particular? Why not the interval 13 to 15, or 10 to 13? Why do we calculate the probability of the tail?

The key is the null hypothesis, $H_0$, which is

James Bond is guessing.

The so-called $p$-value is the probability that the evidence is at least as exceptional as what is observed, given that $H_0$ is true. In this case, $H_0$ has that James Bond is simply guessing for each trial, so there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance that he gets any particular trial correct.
So, what should be considered "at least as exceptional" as getting $13$ out of $16$ correct? Getting $13, 14, 15, 16$ obviously all satisfy this.

Why not the interval... $10$ to $13$?

Because getting $10, 11, 12$ would not be as "unexpected" as getting $13$.
On a related note, it can be argued that getting only  $0, 1, 2, 3$ correct is also exceptional - just in the other direction (James Bond is particularly bad at picking the correct choice). This much depends on the alternative hypothesis. If the alternative hypothesis $H_A$ is

James Bond can correctly predict shaken or stirred, better than chance.

then the $p$-value is just
$$\sum_{k = 0}^3 \frac{\binom{16}{k}}{2^{16}} = \frac{697}{2^{16}} \approx 0.01064$$
since the cases where he gets very few correct are unexceptional. If, however, the alternative hypothesis is something like

James Bond is not guessing.

then the cases where James Bond gets a statistically improbable low number of trials correct (e.g., $0, 1, 2, 3$ for this problem) should be considered "exceptional". Since the distribution is symmetric, we simply have the $p$-value for this case to be double for the other alternative hypothesis, namely, $2 \left( \frac{697}{2^{16}} \right) = \frac{697}{2^{15}} \approx 0.02127$.
